# Obtain pixel values from an image at the mouse position

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mouse, mouseover, pixel

I am trying to obtain the pixel values as and when I move my mouse cursor in Maltab .Can I use `g-input` function in Matlab? I am not getting how to proceed. All the pixel values are doubles.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32900-data-cursor-on-mouse-move/content/getPixelOnMouseMove.m or http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/279649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [`impixelinfo`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/impixelinfo.html) do what you need? This requires Image Processing Toolbox.

Alternatively, can you just use a Data Cursor? For example, type `image` to display a default image. Then in the figure toolbar, click the Data Cursor button (looks like a little yellow square and a blue line, with a black crosshair). Finally click on a pixel in the image to display X and Y coordinates, and RGB values of the pixel. You can pick the data cursor up with the mouse and move it around to display other pixels.

Comment: I have 2 questions.   1]what does index stands for?   2]My image is a single channel but its giving R,G,B values.What does this mean